# Any hints or answers to figure out the unknown value of C?

Tags: integration

Evaluate
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}
\left(\frac{1}{\,\sqrt{\, x^{2} + 4\,}\,} - \frac{C}{x + 2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I am stuck at this question where I should find the value of C for which the integral converges and evaluate the integral for this value of C. Any hints or answers ??.

Comment: Please use mathjax, not pictures. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/how-to-deal-with-users-that-just-wont-use-mathjax).

Comment: If $f(x)\sim A/x$ as $x\to\infty$ with $A$ a nonzero constant, then $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry I’m a newcomer. Next time I’ll use that.

Comment: Sum the integrand $\frac{x+2-C\sqrt{x^2+4}}{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4}}$. Multiply and divide by $(x+2)+C\sqrt{x^2+4}$ to get $\frac{(1-C^2)x^2+4x+4-4C^2}{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4}(x+2+C\sqrt{x^2+4})}$ If $C\neq\pm1$ then you can use the comparizon test with $1/x$ for $x\to\infty$. The quotient of the two functions tends to a non-zero number. Since $\int_{1}^{\infty}1/x$ diverges, then so does this integral.

Comment: For $C=1$ we get $\frac{4x}{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4}(x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4})}$.
This time you can compare with $1/x^2$. But this time, since $\int_{1}^{\infty}1/x^2$ converges so does the integral. Finally, for $C=-1$ we get $\frac{x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4}}$, which you can compare again with $1/x$ and it diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{x}$ in a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ is not an integrable function over there.
So, in order to have a convergent integral, we need $C=1$ to compensate such singular behaviour.
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}-\frac{1}{x+2}$ behaves like $\frac{K}{x^2}$ for $x\to +\infty$ and we are fine. In explicit terms

$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}-\frac{1}{x+2}\right)\,dx = \log\left(\tfrac{3}{\varphi}\right)\approx \varphi-1 $$
where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x+2)^2\geqslant x^2+4$ for $x>0$ therefore 
$$\int^{\infty}_1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}-\frac{C}{x+2}\,dx\geqslant \int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+2)^2}}-\frac{C}{x+2}\,dx=\int^{\infty}_1\frac{1-C}{x+2}\,dx$$
The left side is convergent only if the right side is. That happens only if $C=1$.